# Is it safe to remove @Named annotations without a name?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jsr330

A tonne of code at my company uses the `javax.inject.Named` annotation with the default value, which [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html#value()) indicates is the empty string `""`.

For example:

```
@Named
public class Foo {
   ... 
}
```

This does not appear to add any value, since the empty string doesn't have any semantic meaning. If I remove the `@Named` annotations will there be any harmful effects?

The question [What is javax.inject.Named annotation supposed to be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5415261/1911388) describes how `@Named` functions, but doesn't explain any special significance of the empty string, or why it would be necessary or beneficial to omit the actual name.

The question [When should you explicitly name a Managed Bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19152239/1911388) likewise talks about when you would want to use names to differentiate injectable beans, but doesn't provide any rationale for the use of the empty string as a name.

Can I delete these un-named `@Named` annotations without breaking anything?

Comment: I think the implicit answer here is: This is not what `@Named` was intended for, and the code you describe is a misuse of `@Named`. I would go further and say that `@Named` itself is a mistake nearly 100% of the time. If you want an annotation parameterized by a string, you can make your own, but if you use `@Named` all over the place, you've replaced a *type system* based on annotation types with a "stringly typed" system, with all the lack-of-debuggability that that implies.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Guice `@com.google.inject.name.Named` annotation, which AFAIK was the inspiration for JSR-330's `@javax.inject.Named`, did not have a default value for the string, so `@Named` without an argument would be a compile error. I don't know why the JSR-330 group decided to add a default value.

Comment: @DanielPryden, even in your comments, you haven't actually answered the question. Saying "that is not what `@Named`" and "it is a misuse" doesn't actually answer the questions *Does it have any effect?* and the subsidiary question *Is it safe to delete it?*

Comment: @DanielPryden, in what way is asking, "Does X have any effect?" and the subsidiary question "Is it safe to delete X?" ambiguous? Can you please pinpoint the ambiguity so I can edit my question to remove it?

Comment: _The same applies to CDI beans, EJBs, JPA Entity classes, etc._. That's very much explicit.

Answer (score 3):

`@Named` (javax.inject.Named) is equivalent of `@Component` (org.springframework.stereotype.Component).

When used to annotated a class, it indicates that the class will be scanned and registered. If name is not given, DI framework will use the class type when injecting dependencies.

In short, you can't remove those `@Named` annotation. If you do, everything will be compiled as normal. However, at runtime, you'll get runtime error something like cannot find bean xyz.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know if you will break anything without analyzing all the code that constructs injection keys and all the code that injects any of these bindings.

In some JSR-330 implementations (e.g. Dagger) it's not possible to use a `@Named` annotation with a value constructed at runtime, but in other implementations (e.g. Guice) it is possible and in fact commonly done.

For example, I could imagine a Guice module like:

```
public final class DynamicFooModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final String whichFoo;

    public DynamicFooModule(String whichFoo) {
        this.whichFoo = whichFoo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        Key<Foo> fooKey = Key.get(Foo.class, Names.named(whichFoo));
        Provider<Foo> fooProvider = getProvider(fooKey);
        bind(Foo.class).toProvider(fooProvider);
    }
}
```

This provides a binding for an unannotated `Foo` which delegates to a `@Named(x) Foo`, where `x` is determined by a constructor argument to the module -- which could be constructed at runtime, or derived from some default somewhere, etc.

You could imagine code building an injector like:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
    ...,
    new DynamicFooModule(getSelectedFooConfig()),
    ...);
```

Where `getSelectedFooConfig()` might return `""` as a default or fallback.

In a situation like that, `@Named` without any name could be a reasonable fallback value to use. If your application is doing anything like that, then it is *not* safe to remove the `@Named` bindings, because an un-annotated binding is not equivalent to a binding with an empty string.

I still would argue that this is not a *good* design: it would be better to use a dedicated qualifier annotation for this purpose (e.g. `@ConfigBased("foo-config")`) rather than just using `@Named`. If you were doing that then you could at least identify which strings were being used (or, better yet, eschew strings and use an enum instead).

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, at least in the Guice case I would have to provide an explicit funky binding in order for `@Named` to have any effect?